# Container based Nginx configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, drupal

Seeking help from developers familiar with Wodby container management. The main objective is changing the MIME Types that are gzipped. I'm confused with the documentation for customizing my Nginx container. The documentation:

https://wodby.com/docs/1.0/stacks/drupal/containers/

suggests I copy "/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost.conf", modify it, deploy it the repo and use an environment variable to include it. My problem is, even if I could find this file, which is not mounted on the server when created via Wodby, it does not appear that I'm actually able to change the MIME types or the default_type as they are already defined in the nginx.conf file.

I have also attempted to modify the Wodby stack to mount the /etc/ directory so that I could manually edit the nginx.conf file if I had to, but that only freezes the deployment.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two options

1. clone a repo https://github.com/wodby/nginx/, change the template file `/templates/nginx.conf.tmpl` as much as you need and build your own image. See Makefile (`/Makefile`) for the commands they use to build the image themselves. Use this image as the image for your nginx container from docker-compose.
2. Run a container with the default settings, shell into the container with `docker-compose exec nginx sh` and copy the nginx file from the container (use `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and copy it somewhere). Create a new file locally and mount it via the `docker-compose.yml` for the nginx container like

```
volumes:
 - ./nginx-custom.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```